# Connectedness of parts used in the Banach–Tarski paradox

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, connectedness, paradoxes

A quote from the Wikipedia article ["Axiom of choice"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice#Criticism_and_acceptance):

> One example is the Banach–Tarski paradox which says that it is
>   possible to decompose the 3-dimensional solid unit ball into finitely
>   many pieces and, using only rotations and translations, reassemble the
>   pieces into two solid balls each with the same volume as the original.

I know that at least some of the parts (called *pieces* here) must be non-measurable sets. I wonder if each of them can be chosen to be a path-connected set (otherwise it's really misleading to call them *pieces*, I think).

Comment: If I recall correctly, one of these pieces is a singleton.

Comment: @AsafKaragila A singleton is a path-connected set, right? Just use a constant function that maps $[0,1]$ to its only point. My question is can we make each part to be path-connected.

Comment: Yes, I know, which is why I didn't post an answer. I simply don't know the answer. It sounds a bit unlikely, though. In any case, historically Banach-Tarski didn't specify how many pieces; von Neumann claimed he can do it in $9$, and some time later Sierpinski claimed he can do it in $8$; and only some more time later Robinson proved that you can do it in $5$, but you can't do it in $4$. (All this appears in Halbeisen's *Combinatorial Set Theory* which includes a chapter on the Banach-Tarski paradox.)

Comment: There was an exposition of this result in American Mathematical Monthly. I can't recall the title or year.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dekker and de Groot proved ([Decompositions of a sphere](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm43/fm43119.pdf),  *Fund. Math.* **43** (1956), 185–194) that the pieces can be made to be totally imperfect, and hence connected and locally connected.  I don't know about path connected, though.

Although you didn't ask about this, one can also argue that "decompose and reassemble" implicitly suggests that the rearrangement can take place using continuous motions during which the pieces never intersect.  That this is possible was proved by Trevor Wilson
([A continuous movement version of the Banach–Tarski paradox: A solution to de Groot's problem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/27588401.pdf), *J. Symb. Logic* **70** (2005), 946–952).  But I don't know if there is a common generalization of the Dekker–de Groot result above and Wilson's result.